# How to cancel WPF app closing from Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, navigationwindow

I'm using a WPF NavigationWindow and some Pages and would like to be able to know when the application is closing from a Page.
How can this be done without actively notifying the page from the NavigationWindow_Closing event handler?

I'm aware of the technique [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#Navigation_Lifetime), but unfortunately NavigationService_Navigating isn't called when the application is closed.

Comment: You mean that the `Page` should be notified when the application decides to close? What could it do that you can't already do from the `Window` that hosts the page?

Comment: @Jon: As an example the Page may have to save the state of some UI elements to settings. The Window doesn't have access to these UI elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is have the pages involved support an interface such as:

```
public interface ICanClose
{
     bool CanClose();
}
```

Implement this interface at the page level:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page,  ICanClose
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool CanClose()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the navigation window, check to see if the child is of ICanClose:

```
private void NavigationWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    ICanClose canClose = this.Content as ICanClose;

    if (canClose != null && !canClose.CanClose())
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: [+1] I came up with exactly this solution for now, though my method is called CancelApplicationClosing() :-)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, your problem is how to get access to the content hosted inside the `NavigationWindow`. Knowing that the window itself is closing is trivial, e.g. there is the `Closing` event you can subscribe to.

To get the `Page` hosted in the `NavigationWindow`, you can use [`VisualTreeHelper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) to drill down into its descendants until you find the one and only `WebBrowser` control. You could code this manually, but there is [good code like this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) ready to use on the net.

After you get the `WebBrowser`, it's trivially easy to get at the content with the [`WebBrowser.Document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document.aspx) property.